# Kendo tree Check Nodes all nodes with same name programatically

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-treeview

Actually functionality is working fine if we have only one node with same name. 
Here i need to check Both Nodes with same name "Bar"  [Tree view should Check like this through Programatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJo7F.png)

```
  <script>
    $("#tree").kendoTreeView({
      checkboxes: {
        checkChildren: true
      },

      dataSource: {
        data: [
          { text: "Foo", expanded: true, items: [
            { text: "Bar" },
            { text: "Bar" },
            { text: "Baz" }
          ] }
        ]
      }
    });

    var treeview = $("#tree").data("kendoTreeView");

    var bar = treeview.findByText("Bar");

    treeview.dataItem(bar).set("checked", true);
  </script>
```